# Counting string occurrences in list

Tags: python

I'm trying to work on a simple python problem hosted on [hackerrankteam](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-birthday-bar) but I'm having difficulty with the count function for lists in Python. I've tried multiple test cases but my count function always returns 0.

- Objective: count the number of occurrences that consecutive squares equals the number of days.

Is this an issue with the type of list? Is there an easier way for me count the values in one line instead of having to check the valued pairs and then count the sums?

```
import sys

def solve(size, squares, day, month):
    check = [sum(squares[nums:nums+month]) == day for nums in range(0,len(squares))]
    print (check)   #Test list output
    count = check.count('True')
    return count

#Test Cases 1
# size = 6
# squares = [1,1,1,1,1,1]
# day, month = (3,2)
#Output 0

#Test Cases 2
# size = 1
# squares = [4]
# day, month = (4,1)
#Output 1

#Test Cases 3
size = 5
squares = [1,2,1,3,2] 
day, month = [3,2]
#Output 2

#Custom User Input:
# size = int(input().strip())
# squares = list(map(int, input().strip().split(' ')))
# day, month = input().strip().split(' ')
# day, month = [int(day), int(month)]
result = solve(size, squares, day, month)
print(result)
```

Comment: You can use the fact the `True` is treated as 1 and `False` as 0, so you can simply do `count = sum(sum(squares[nums:nums+month]) == day for nums in range(0,len(squares))); return count`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm a bit new to python programming so picking up the shortcuts will really help with my studies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
check.count('True')
```

This code is counting the number of occurrences of the *string* `'True'`.

It should instead be:

```
check.count(True)
```

You could also simply use this:

```
sum(check)
```

Comment: Ah proper syntax strikes again. Is the reason why the list won't properly count the values because the values in the list are bool typed?

Comment: `True != 'True'`, `==` returns a `bool` value which is what you have in the list.